# Merging Rows on a Unique Identifier without Eliminating Unique Data and Adding Values Together

Tags: vba, excel, merge, row, uniqueidentifier

I have a large excel spreadsheet where I need to merge rows on a unique identifier. I'm trying to develop an Excel VBA macro but still lack the proficiency to tackle this.

Here is a picture of an example of what I'm trying to do. The data including the headers are all made up for the example but what is demonstrated down below is exactly what I'm trying to do.

***EXAMPLE:***

**Before:**

```
Unique ID | Item Name | Item Description | Numbers Sold | Notes
11111     | Cupcakes  | Red              | 10           | Good
11111     | Cupcakes  | Red              | 15           | Testing
11111     | Cupcakes  | Red              | 10           | Bad
22222     | Brownies  | Brown            | 11           | Example
22222     | Brownies  | Brown            | 11           | Example2
22222     | Brownies  | Brown            | 26           | Example3
```

**After:**

```
Unique ID | Item Name | Item Description | Numbers Sold | Notes
11111     | Cupcakes  | Red              | 35           | Good, Testing, Bad
22222     | Brownies  | Brown            | 37           | Example, Example 2, Example 3
```

As you can see, similar data is merged together on the first 3 columns based upon the unique ID. The 4th column containing number values are added up. Any unique values in the 5th column are kept together as unique data.

I would appreciate any help or tips anyone can give me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

okay here it goes,
A visual presentation.

Set Up Sheet 1

[image: Set Up Sheet 1]

Set Up Sheet 2

[image: Sheet2]

Add a Button to Sheet 1

[image: Add Button]

Go to the VBA Editor By Hitting Ctrl & F11 or Use the Developer Ribbon

[image: Dev Tab]

Insert A Module

[image: Insert Module]

Copy and Paste this code there

```
Sub GetUnique()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = vNum
    Next vNum
    FiltDat
End Sub
Sub FiltDat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, Sm As Range, c As Range
    Dim fRws As Long, fRng As Range, fc As Range, fx As String, cma
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 9
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
    End With
    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        With ws
            .Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=c
            Set Sm = .Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
            c.Offset(0, 3) = Application.Sum(Sm.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            fRws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            Set fRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "E"), .Cells(fRws, "E")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            cx = fRng.Rows.Count
            fx = ""
            y = 1
            For Each fc In fRng.Cells
                cma = IIf(y <> cx, ",", "")
                fx = fx & fc & cma
                y = y + 1
                c.Offset(, 1) = fc.Offset(0, -3)
                c.Offset(, 2) = fc.Offset(0, -2)

            Next fc
            c.Offset(0, 4) = fx
            .AutoFilterMode = 0
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Exit the VBA Editor and Assign Macro to The Button, Assign GetUnique Macro

[image: Assign]

[image: GetUniq]

Click the button and go to Sheet 2 to see the results.

[image]